# how to return nothing ( empty array) with array.map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-map

Right now, if 'Everything' in the list is detected, the output becomes [""].
Expected output: []

```
Copy.names = rule.names.map(function(x) {                                
    if (x.name ==='Everything') {                                   
        return '';
    } else {
        return x.name;
    }
});
```

Comment: just write `return;` Also, consider using Array.prototype.filter for this.

Comment: if i do that, it returns 'null' which I don't want

Comment: You probably want to use a method such as `filter`. `map` returns an element for every element you iterate over.

Comment: @Angular Change `map` to `filter`, `return ''` to `false` and `return x.name` to `true`

Comment: Or you could simply put `return x.name === 'Everything'` instead of the whole if...else

Comment: Map will always return SOMETHING, you will need to change it to filter or, using a regular for loop to get the desired behavior.

Comment: guys, my backend expects an empty list [] if "everything" is selected. Otherwise, it expects a list of the other names ['apple', 'orange'] So what's the best way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing elements with Array.map in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289/removing-elements-with-array-map-in-javascript)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use Array.prototype.filter:

```
Copy.names = rule.names.filter(function(x) {                                
    return x.name !=='Everything';
}).map(function (x) {
    return x.name;
});
```

Comment: I did this, it's actually returning 'Everything' , which is wrong

Comment: If you are using the code in your original post, the problem is that Array.prototype.map applies a transformation to every element in your list.  You must instead use some logic to remove or ignore elements you don't want.  Array.prototype.map does not have the ability to ignore elements alone, so it must be combined with another function, like Array.prototype.filter:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Shouldn't it be `x.name !== 'Everything'`?

Answer (score 17):

Another solution with Array.filter():

```
names.map(
  (x) => x.name === 'Everything' && x.name
).filter(Boolean)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use Lodash (which I highly recommend), you can deal with it in elegant way by using `_.flatMap`:

```
Copy.names = _.flatMap(rule.names, function(x) {
    if (x.name ==='Everything') {                                   
        return [];
    } else {
        return [x.name];
    }
})
```

As you can see, it's similiar to `map`, except that you return array of items instead of item.

Comment: One caveat to this approach is that you will create a temporary array for every element in rule.names.  This isn't a big deal for just a few elements, but can become costly with large lists.

Comment: please dont ever import a heavy dependency for just one function...

Comment: @samthet I think the package gets reduced in the build package to include only the used functions

Answer (score 2):

If you can use ES6, you can use generator for that:

```
Copy.names = Array.from(function* () {
    for (var x of rule.names) {
       if (x.name ==='Everything') {                                   
            // do nothing
       } else {
            yield x.name;
       }
    }
})
```

If not... you can always go for imperative way:

```
Copy.names = []

for (var x of rule.names) {
   if (x.name ==='Everything') {                                   
        // do nothing
   } else {
        Copy.names.push(x.name);
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that the first approach (Using Array.from with generator) works. I tried it in different ES6 enabled environments and it always returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

An answer I wrote [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36557522/4526479) covers this, but if you want to be able to accomplish the transform of `Array.map()` but also to change the output length, you would need to use `Array.reduce()`.

Usually, though, it will make more sense to filter--preferably before you map, but if needed, then after.

Answer (score 0):

For this you should use reduce instead of map, here an example:

```
Copy.names = rule.names.reduce(function (arr, x) {
  x.name !== 'Everything' && arr.push(x.name)
  return arr
}, [])
```