# How can i pick out the integers that are smaller or equal to 60 with .map array method

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, operators, operator-keyword

```
 const recipes = [
  {
    title: 'Crepes',
    duration: 60,
    ingredients: ['butter', 'flour', 'eggs', 'milk', 'salt'],
    servings: 3
  },
  {
    title: 'Scrambled Eggs',
    duration: 20,
    ingredients: ['eggs', 'milk', 'salt'],
    servings: 2
  },
  {
    title: 'Vegan Salmon',
    duration: 60 * 24 * 3, // 3 days
    ingredients: ['carrots', 'olive oil', 'nori sheets', 'liquid smoke', 'soy sauce'],
    servings: 10
  },
  {
    title: 'Carot Cake',
    duration: 120,
    ingredients: ['carrots', 'flour', 'eggs', 'salt', 'milk', 'sugar'],
    servings: 10
  }
]
```

I want to create an array like this:

`['Crepes (60min)', ...]`

Thats my code so far:

```
    const titlesWithDuration = recipes.map((titles) => {
      return `${titles.title} (${titles.duration}min)`; 
    }); 

console.log(titlesWithDuration)
```

Problem is, if i use things like operators, for example:

`titles.duration <= 60`

i will get this:

```
["Crepes (truemin)","Scrambled Eggs (truemin)","Vegan Salmon (falsemin)","Carot Cake (falsemin)"]
```

How can i use operators which give me a string output?

Comment: You should probably use `.filter()` to create a new array of the objects you want, and then use your current code to format the strings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing elements with Array.map in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289/removing-elements-with-array-map-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` does a one-for-one mapping, but in your example, you want to leave out some elements. That's a *filtering* operation.

For the vast majority of use cases, you can just [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
const titlesWithDuration = recipes
    .filter(({duration}) => duration <= 60)
    .map(({title, duration}) => `${title} (${duration}min)`);
```

Live Example:

```js
const recipes = [
  {
    title: 'Crepes',
    duration: 60,
    ingredients: ['butter', 'flour', 'eggs', 'milk', 'salt'],
    servings: 3
  },
  {
    title: 'Scrambled Eggs',
    duration: 20,
    ingredients: ['eggs', 'milk', 'salt'],
    servings: 2
  },
  {
    title: 'Vegan Salmon',
    duration: 60 * 24 * 3, // 3 days
    ingredients: ['carrots', 'olive oil', 'nori sheets', 'liquid smoke', 'soy sauce'],
    servings: 10
  },
  {
    title: 'Carot Cake',
    duration: 120,
    ingredients: ['carrots', 'flour', 'eggs', 'salt', 'milk', 'sugar'],
    servings: 10
  }
];

const titlesWithDuration = recipes
    .filter(({duration}) => duration <= 60)
    .map(({title, duration}) => `${title} (${duration}min)`);

console.log(titlesWithDuration);
```

In the **rare** situation where you want to avoid multiple trips through the array, you could use a generator function version of `filter` and [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) (using its mapping callback argument) to build the result:

```
function* filter(it, callback) {
    for (const element of it) {
        if (callback(element)) {
            yield element;
        }
    }
}

const titlesWithDuration = Array.from(
    filter(recipes, ({duration}) => duration <= 60),
    ({title, duration}) => `${title} (${duration}min)`
);
```

Live Example:

```js
const recipes = [
  {
    title: 'Crepes',
    duration: 60,
    ingredients: ['butter', 'flour', 'eggs', 'milk', 'salt'],
    servings: 3
  },
  {
    title: 'Scrambled Eggs',
    duration: 20,
    ingredients: ['eggs', 'milk', 'salt'],
    servings: 2
  },
  {
    title: 'Vegan Salmon',
    duration: 60 * 24 * 3, // 3 days
    ingredients: ['carrots', 'olive oil', 'nori sheets', 'liquid smoke', 'soy sauce'],
    servings: 10
  },
  {
    title: 'Carot Cake',
    duration: 120,
    ingredients: ['carrots', 'flour', 'eggs', 'salt', 'milk', 'sugar'],
    servings: 10
  }
];

function* filter(it, callback) {
    for (const element of it) {
        if (callback(element)) {
            yield element;
        }
    }
}

const titlesWithDuration = Array.from(
    filter(recipes, ({duration}) => duration <= 60),
    ({title, duration}) => `${title} (${duration}min)`
); 

console.log(titlesWithDuration);
```

Answer (score 1):

Array's map and filter methods will help to do the expected result. map will do the transition  and filter will help to apply condition.

```
result = recipes.filter(ele=>ele.duration <=60).map(ele=> `${ele.title} (${ele.duration}min)`);
```

result would be

['Crepes (60min)', 'Scrambled Eggs (20min)']